# Обучение 1С v8.3 На базе v8.2

Tags: 1с

Я в позапрошлом году купил коробочную версию 1С предприятие 8.2 для обучению программированию, вопрос в том что вышла 1С Предприятие 8.3 мне интересно какие у меня возникнут проблемы с переходом из версии 8.2 в версию 8.3 и стоит ли мне изучать 1С программирование с купленной мной коробки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучайте 8.2. Изменения в 8.3. в основном либо косметические, либо связаны с администрированием и инфраструктурой, в частности появился linux-клиент.

[Полный список изменений](http://downloads.v8.1c.ru/content/Platform/8_3_1_531/1cv8upd.htm#4cc794a1-7d56-11e1-b5d1-e61f135f174b)

Кроме того, учитывая целый зоопарк версий 1С, можно с уверенностью сказать, что конфигурации, написанные под 8.2 будут жить на 8.2 до смерти и переход на 8.3 может быть оправдан лишь в рекламных целях. К слову сказать, огромное количество предприятий продолжает работать на 7.7., снятой с продажи.

На вопрос можно ли писать на 8.3., имея учебники по 8.2.? Можно ответить утвердительно, с вероятностью близкой к 1 при обучении с изменениями столкнуться не придется.

Comment: спасибо хороший человек. помог мое мнение подтвердить

Answer (score 0):

Для обучения можно выбрать любую платформу *(рекомендую все таки 8.3)*, изменений мало, но можно поставить обе платформы, т.к. обновление учебных версий насколько я помню бесплатно. Если планируете изучать разработку под **мобильные платформы**, то ставьте **1С 8.3**, так же у 8.3 доработана поддержка linux систем. К книге, которая у вас должна уже быть *(1С:Предприятие 8.2. Практическое пособие разработчика)* рекомендую посмотреть бесплатный курс для начинающих [Программирование в 1С за 21 день](http://vk.cc/3ELdgl)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сразу на 8.3 переходите. Как писалось выше, изменения минимальны. Но в 8.3 более менее приличный редактор кода. Да и вообще более дружественен к программистам.

Answer (score 0):

Удобнее учиться на 8.3, как уже сказали она более дружелюбна к программистам. Еще рекомендую книгу "Практическое пособие разработчика", Радченко. В твоей коробке она должна быть. Либо можно сказать бесплатно http://online.1c.ru/catalog/free/learning.php